# Will iOS 7 support application developed for older version of iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, ios7

We are planning for a new mobile application for iPhones/iPads this month and we are outsourcing this project as we dont have much knowledge about the subject. Could someone tell me if current iOS applications will run on iOS 7?

I would  appreciate help in this as I tried to search but could not find related articles as most of the articles talk about features and not backwards compatibility.

Comment: iOS 7 is still under NDA, isn't it? If so, discussing it on a public forum like StackOverflow isn't allowed.

Comment: iOS is always backward compatible from what I understand, It only becomes incompatible if you use a newer feature not supported for iOS

Comment: @dreamlax Is it appropriate to flag/down-vote questions which violate Apple's NDA? Or it that just a legal issue left to the OP?

Comment: @IsaiahTurner - it's not appropriate to flag or downvote questions for perceived NDA violations. NDAs are not Stack Overflow's concern, its up to the poster. IMO nothing in this question has anything to do with the NDA anyway. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/should-moderators-enforce-ndas-for-software-vendors

Answer (score 1):

Sure. It will support older versions of iOS. If not millions of applications in Appstore will be unusable in iOS 7. You need to download iOS 7 SDK once available to exploit iOS 7 specific features, thats all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes current iOS application will run on iOS 7, because apple will take care that if they launch new iOS then they create new iOS in such a way that it's always compatible with older iOS apps other wise if someone upgrade the iOS and the apps of previously developed will not work on it then they loose their customers/users. So don't worry new iOS 7 will also support apps developed for iOS5/iOS6. There were only new features in iOS7.

Answer (score 1):

Although iOS 7 has seen a major overhaul in UI field as well as several back end changes too. But the main point for your question is that any application if working on previous versions of iOS should work in iOS 7 too. The OS will take care of all the UI instances drawings in different versions of OS. The situation where the applications supporting newer versions of OS not working on older versions is that they use some features only available to a specific version of OS or later.

Answer (score 0):

It would run in iOS 7, but probably not as you would expect it to run, so my recommendation is to create 2 (or 4 if you build for iPad) 1 for iOS 6 - and one for iOS 7 + just detect the iOS version and load the storyboard for the appropriate version

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to start development in the latest available version of iOS. In this case 7 is the latest with all the support for developers. You can get the relative iOS SDK and Xcode.

Long Story Short: Start Development in the latest iOS and nothing shall go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From the research I had done, indeed app built using 6.1 SDK and Xcode 4.6 will run on iOS7, however, the app will have an iOS6 look and feel on iOS7.